# How to run leetcode linked list problems in local machine?

Tags: javascript, linked-list

How can I run the linked list programs in the local machine?
When I run this code in their input box it running but I can't seem to run this program in the local machine.

```
  function ListNode(val, next) {
      this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
      this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
  }
 
/**
 * @param {ListNode} list1
 * @param {ListNode} list2
 * @return {ListNode}
 */

var mergeTwoLists = function (l1, l2) {
  var mergedHead = { val: -1, next: null },
    crt = mergedHead;
  while (l1 && l2) {
    if (l1.val > l2.val) {
      crt.next = l2;
      l2 = l2.next;
    } else {
      crt.next = l1;
      l1 = l1.next;
    }
    crt = crt.next;
  }
  crt.next = l1 || l2;
  return mergedHead.next;
};

mergeTwoLists([1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4]);
```

Comment: You are not passing **Node Lists**.

Comment: @PM77-1 can you modify this code so that it can run in local machine. I already search google for this but I can't seem to find a way?

Comment: In order to merge *linked lists* you need first to **create** them. Apparently the website does it for you.

Comment: @PM77-1 Yeah, The thing is that I wanna know how this work behind the scene. I mean the whole process. I can practice in website but I am comfortable in my own local code editor so I am trying to replicate the process in local machine

Comment: You need to write your own code to create multiple individual nodes, and set their properties to create two linked lists.  If the above code is indeed your own, you should not have problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use these two helper functions to convert an array to linked list and  vice versa, which is essentially what the LeetCode framework does for you behind the scenes.

```
const listFromArray = a => a.length ? new ListNode(a[0], listFromArray(a.slice(1)))  
                                    : null;
const arrayFromList = head => head ? [head.val].concat(arrayFromList(head.next)) 
                                   : [];
```

In your case you can use them like this:

```
const result = arrayFromList(
    mergeTwoLists(listFromArray([1, 2, 4]), listFromArray([1, 3, 4]))
);
```

Comment: totally helped me out, thank you @trincot

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run the `mergeTwoLists` method locally by providing `ListNode` and `LinkedList` classes that I generated. As one can see below, the `runCase` helper function takes two `ListNodes` (`LinkedList` heads), merges them, and prints the result. We can create a linked list using `toArray` with LeetCode test case inputs and convert the result into an array using the `fromArray` function of the `LinkedList`.

```js
class ListNode {
  constructor(val=0, next=null) {
      this.val = val;
      this.next = next;             
  }
}

class LinkedList {
  constructor(head = null) {
    this.head = head
  }

  static fromArray(array) {
    const linkedList = new LinkedList();

    for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      const node = new ListNode(array[i]);
      node.next = linkedList.head;
      linkedList.head = node;
    }

    return linkedList;
  }

  toArray() {
    const array = [];
    let current = this.head;

    while (current) {
      array.push(current.val);
      current = current.next;
    }

    return array;
  }
}

/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val, next) {
 *     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *     this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
 * }
 *
 * @param {ListNode} node1
 * @param {ListNode} node2
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
var mergeTwoLists = function(node1, node2) {
  let loco = new ListNode();
  let current = loco;

  while (node1 && node2) {
    if (node1.val > node2.val) {
      current.next = node2;
      node2 = node2.next;
    } else {
      current.next = node1;
      node1 = node1.next;
    }
    current = current.next;
  }
  current.next = node1 || node2;

  return loco.next;
};

const runCase = (array1, array2) => {
  const node1 = LinkedList.fromArray(array1).head;
  const node2 = LinkedList.fromArray(array2).head;

  const result = mergeTwoLists(node1, node2);
  const linkedList = new LinkedList(result);
  console.log(linkedList.toArray());
}

runCase([1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4]); // [1,1,2,3,4,4]
runCase([], []); // []
runCase([], [0]); // [0]
```

#### Reference

- [21. Merge Two Sorted Lists by LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/)
- [How to Implement a Linked List in JavaScript by Sarah Chima Atuonwu](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/implementing-a-linked-list-in-javascript/)