# Why am I getting an error on this code when I run it on Pycharm but it works on leetcode?

Tags: linked-list, pycharm

I am starting to practice Linked list on Leetcode and I as trying to do the problem "203. Remove Linked List Elements". I tried to check the solutions of the exercise on Leetcode and when I try to run the solution on Pycharm it give me an error` "File "C:\Users\wasiq\PycharmProjects\Practice-DS&A\practice.py", line 12, in removeElements" but it works on Leetcode
if current_node.next.val == val:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'val'"
The code that I am trying to run is below:
class ListNode:
def **init**(self, val=0, next=None):
self.val = val
self.next = next
class Solution:
def removeElements(self, head: [ListNode], val: int) -> [ListNode]:
dummy_head = ListNode(-1)
dummy_head.next = head

```
    current_node = dummy_head
    while current_node.next != None:
        if current_node.next.val == val:
            current_node.next = current_node.next.next
        else:
            current_node = current_node.next

    return dummy_head.next
```

sol = Solution()
print(sol.removeElements([1,2,6,3,4,5,6],6))

I tried various things but it doesnt seem to work, I am probably missing something which I can not figure out as I am still new to this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run leetcode linked list problems in local machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71914400/how-to-run-leetcode-linked-list-problems-in-local-machine)

Comment: Same for python: [AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'val' in linked list LeetCode challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72597517/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-val-in-linked-list-leetcode-cha/72598123#72598123)